# How to configurate http_post_2xx in blackbox exporter?

Tags: port, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus, and I have been trying to set up blackbox exporter for monitoring my server by the **http_post_2xx** module but not http_2xx module. However, given so much researching on the internet, I still do not figure out.

Here is the background of my situation: I used to monitor my website available or not by Postman. After sending a post request, I should be able to receive a signal indicating the status is 200 OK or could not get any response, manually. This is ineffective and unresponsible as I should not be noticed an error from my website-visitor but not myself. Therefore, I turn to Prometheus.

Blackbox exporter seems like my solution. I build blackbox exporter on my server, and the configure file is like this:

```
modules:
  http_post_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 5s
    http:
      method: POST
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      body: '{text: "hi"}'
```

I configure the prometheus.yml in this way:

```
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
        module: [http_post_2xx]
    static_configs:
        - targets:
            - 10.0.100.130:2001 
            - 10.0.100.130:2002 # The IP address I want to monitor
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: 10.0.100.130:9115 # Turn on this port for sending metrics
```

The dashboard I apply is [5345](https://grafana.com/dashboards/5345), but I got something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJRtE.png)

I do not know why the HTTP Status Code is N/A or No, but the status from Postman is 200 OK. Is there anything wrong of my configuration?

Comment: When you hover over one of the cells with an error, what does it say the error is?

Comment: I get the error message as "Multiple Series Error" when I hover over the red corner of the HTTP Status Code. I assume the reason for this error is as the purpose of this grafana dashboard is for monitoring one HTTP state only, but I edit the targets within static_configs as couples.

Comment: However, I get a value of 0 with the this query: probe_success{instance="10.0.100.130:2002",job="blackbox"}. @brian-brazil

Comment: It sounds like this dashboard isn't designed for your setup, you may have to add some labels to the selectors it uses.

Comment: Without grafana, I got the debug message like "level=debug msg="Invalid HTTP response status code, wanted 2xx" status_code=400", what does this mean, actually?

Comment: I figure it out where was I wrong. The format of JSON is incorrect, as it should be {"text": "hi"}, but not {text: "hi"}. Thank you so much, @brian-brazil

Comment: @brian-brazil: I am having similar issue and i tried the configuration as used in the above post but still i am not able to get it working. Have been trying to get this working for more than a week now but to no avail. Can you kindly help me out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806576/configuring-prometheus-for-spring-boot-health-check-monitoring)? I have made some edits to my post after trying out different things.