# Configuring Prometheus for Spring Boot health check monitoring

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus

We have few Spring Boot applications that have health check implemented. The response for those checks was changed to JSON format based on @Thiru's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806576/configuring-prometheus-for-spring-boot-health-check-monitoring#comment92542176_52806954). I now get the following response:

[image]

Prometheus server is running on Ubuntu instance. Spring boot services that have to be monitored are running on Windows server 2016. I have installed *blackbox-exporter* (version `0.12.0.windows-amd64`) on Windows server after seeing [this](https://medium.com/the-telegraph-engineering/how-prometheus-and-the-blackbox-exporter-makes-monitoring-microservice-endpoints-easy-and-free-of-a986078912ee) post.

Following change was done on client (Windows server with IP: `172.16.x.yz`) side in `blackbox.yml`:

```
modules:
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    http:
  http_post_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 5s
    http:
      method: POST
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      body: '{"status": "UP"}'
  ...
  ...
```

On Prometheus server, following is the content of `prometheus.yml`:

```
...
...
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      #module: [http_2xx]  # Look for a HTTP 200 response.
      module: [http_post_2xx]  # Look for a HTTP 200 response.
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - http://172.16.x.yz:6300/serviceA/actuator/health
        - http://172.16.x.yz:6340/serviceB/actuator/health
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: 172.16.x.yz:9115  # The blackbox exporter's real hostname:port.
```

After making above changes on client and server, when i restart both the `blackbox-exporter` and `prometheus`, i see that Prometheus *always* shows `State` as UP even if the two services that the exporter is monitoring go down. Seems Prometheus is displaying the status of the `blackbox-exporter` and not for the services. Any suggestion how i can fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use some kind of tools which helps in exporting the spring health as prometheus exporter. Basically, exporter which helps in converting json data from an http url into prometheus metrics using jsonpath like:

- https://github.com/project-sunbird/prometheus-jsonpath-exporter
- https://github.com/thirunar/prometheus-spring-boot-info-exporter

Comment: Thanks for the response. Kindly check UPDATE section in my post

Comment: Do you have actuator enabled in spring boot?

Comment: It has the health endpoint in JSON. Both solutions which is mentioned above, will only work with JSON output

Comment: If that's specifically required for Prometheus, then i don't think it will be enabled. I will have to check with developer. Is there no other way which can directly leverage the health check code without modifying anything further in the code?

Comment: I'm the developer of `prometheus-spring-boot-info-exporter`. AFAIK, there is no proper solution for this. One another way could be, to generate alert when is no metrics for a ceratin amount of time

Comment: Ok but when you say to generate alert when no metric for certain time, i guess you mean monitoring the target host itself and not the app that's running on target host, correct? If that's the case, i guess it will lead to same issue that i'm facing right now due to lack of actuator. BTW, devs use `gradle`. I was just checking [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus) link. I would like to first test out the developer's code (by changing the port) so it doesn't affect current set up but i'm not sure what all do i need to use from the above link. (1/2)...

Comment: (2/2)...Besides running the two compile commands mentioned for `Gradle` in the link i mentioned above, do i just need to add `@EnablePrometheusMetrics` in the healthcheck java code? Will that suffice?

Comment: The alert will be generated in both cases. To make the `prometheus-spring-boot-exporter ` / `prometheus-jsonpath-exporter`, you have use actuator in your app. Please follow the steps in (this)[https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/] link. That will give you `/health` endpoint from which the `prometheus-spring-boot-exporter` scraps the metrics.

Comment: Hello. Kindly check UPDATE 2 after developer enabled actuator feature. Will this require fix from your side?

Comment: Can you please share the yml and `/health` response

Comment: Updated `UPDATE 2` with required details.

Comment: I have updated `UPDATE 2`. It will publish the metrics

Comment: Thanks Thiru. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thiru for your help! I can now see the correct status. :) Just one query: it shows endpoint as the exporter URL (`http://xyz.xx.y.z:9158/metrics`) in the first column. How can i show the service name there so that it's easy to recognize each row with its service name? Does it mean the developer will have to add extra key-pairs in JSON response besides the `status`?

Comment: Can you kindly tell me how i can use a user-friendly label for each row that is displayed in dashboard? The label i have mentioned above in `D:\prometheus-spring-boot-info-exporter-master\example\config.yml` i.e., `label: dataservice-dev` doesn't show up in the dashboard. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I think, the exporter has a `tag` called `instance-id` which you can use it as label. Can you share the response and the grafana config?

Comment: I am not using `Grafana` right now. I only want to use `Prometheus` for now for displaying all the services' status. In Prometheus dashboard, i wanted an easily identifiable name for each service, for example, my-service-dev, my-service-qa etc. If you see `UPDATE 3`, it shows the first column (Endpoint) as the exporter URL and the `Labels` column displays `IP:Port` which isn't helpful especially when there will be multiple endpoints to display. To add to the problem, even the `IP:Port` is the same as that of the one shown in first column and not of the service that is being monitored.

Comment: Also, i could not find any mention of `instance-id` in your exporter (https://github.com/thirunar/prometheus-spring-boot-info-exporter/blob/master/example/config.yml). I hope you meant checking in this link only.

Comment: Sorry, I will update the config asap. I'm afraid that you may grafana as there is a label to distinguish the services. Not sure how to do it with prometheus.

Comment: Oh man! :( Does it mean that if an exporter is running on a target box where it is monitoring, say five services, then for each service, it will display a common `IP:Port` both in `Endpoint` and `Label` and that will be that of the exporter's i.e., `xyz.xx.y.z:9158`?

Comment: This solution is not working for me so i have removed it as an answer. The issue seems to be that although this is exporting the data fine but when any of the services (that the exporter is looking for) goes down on the instance where the exporter is running, the exporter itself goes down, which is not i was looking for. Due to this behaviour, Prometheus shows the endpoint itself as down. So functionality wise your module does the job but it's not actually _monitoring_ it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. will try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

As my opinion, prometheus targets actually show that the scrape target is in up or down state. It's not about the healthcheck endpoint state. You can only check the healthcheck endpoint status in probe_success metrics( 1 is up and 0 is down ) . You can check the following screenshots.
Sorry for my bad english.

[image: Targets status]

[image: Real Status of endpoint]